# How to produce multiples of numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get ruby to output

```
1 
22 
333
4444
```

I have to use a nested `while` loop and an `if` statement. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: `(1..4).each { |n| puts n.to_s * n }`

Comment: This is where i'm at so far  
i = 1
while (i < 7)
  puts i
  i = i + 1
end                   The problem is, is that i have to have one 1 two 2's three 3's and so on but i'm really new to this and not sure how to implement it. My homework states that i need to use 2 while loops and an if statement. Im not asking for the answer rather then a walkthrough of how to solve it.

Comment: `puts "1 22 333 4444"`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: i wish i could do that but my professor likes to assign us stuff that he never taught and expect us to some how get exactly what he wants. i can get it do count from 1 to 6 but now i some how need to get the number to go 1 22 333 4444 etc. im lost :(

Comment: Use `i.to_s * i` in your `while` loop. I don't see why you need 2 `while` loops or an `if` expression.

Comment: thats giving me a infinite loop of 1's. i'm sorry if im not getting this. Im sure if I dont use a nested while loop and a if statement and still get the same result he will still give me credit. As long as i dont just use puts "1 22 333 4444"

Comment: You can make an open-ended loop and `break` if it's looped enough times. That would give you two loops.

Comment: @CarySwoveland haha, for no dynamic input passed, constant response output can be simply `puts "1 22 333 4444"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried:

> puts (1..4).map{|i| i.to_s * i}.join(" ")

It yielded

> 1 22 333 4444

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
(1..4).each{ |i| i.times{ print i }; puts "" }
```

**Explaination**

- uses a [range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) and iterates through each item and prints the
- current item required no. of time i.e. current item
- at the end adds a new line so the next prints start on a new line